# In Slick, how to provide default columns for Table

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have some columns all my tables share, so I'd like to provide the default columns for all the tables. Following is what I have tried so far. I am using Slick 3.0.

```
// created_at and updated_at are the columns every table share
abstract class BaseTable[T](tag: Tag, tableName: String) 
     extends Table[T](tag, tableName) {

  def currentWhenInserting = new Timestamp((new Date).getTime)

  def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("created_at", O.Default(currentWhenInserting))

  def updatedAt = column[Timestamp]("updated_at", O.Default(currentWhenInserting))

}
```

And the simple way to implement this seems like the following.

```
case class Student(
  name: String, age: Int, 
  created_at: Timestamp, updated_at: Timestamp
)

class Students(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Student](tag, "students"){

  def name = column[String]("name")
  def age = column[Int]("age")

  override def * : ProvenShape[Student] = 
        (name, age, createdAt, updatedAt).shaped <> 
        (Student.tupled, Student.unapply _)
}
```

But it's not desirable.

First, **force every table row case class to incoporate created_at and updated_at**. If I have more fields that would be totally unacceptable from the API design angle.

Second, write the two **createdAt, updatedAt** in **(name, age, createdAt, updatedAt)** explicitly. This is not what I expect about Default row.

My ideal way of solving this would be like the following:

```
case class Student(name: String, age: Int)

class Students(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Student](tag, "students"){    

  def name = column[String]("name")
  def age = column[Int]("age")

  override def * : ProvenShape[Student] = 
        (name, age).shaped <> 
        (Student.tupled, Student.unapply _)
}
```

That is, **write some method in BaseTable or Define BaseCaseClass to avoid explicitly writing the extra two fields in table definition like Students and row case class definition Student.**

However, after a painful struggle, still can get it done.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A start may be to make `Student` extend a base object which has `createdAt` and `updatedAt`. Not sure if you can use that somehow to make `*` less verbose. Only throwing ideas - not a Scala/Slick expert.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following pattern:

```
case class Common(arg0: String, arg1: String)

trait Commons { this: Table[_] =>
  def arg0 = column[String]("ARG0", O.Length(123))
  def arg1 = column[String]("ARG1", O.Length(123))

  def common = (arg0, arg1).<> [Meta, (String, String)](
    r => {
      val (arg0, arg1) = r
      Meta(arg0, arg1)
    },
    o => Some(o.arg0, o.arg1)
  )
}

case class MyRecord(a: String, b: String, common: Common)

class MyRecords(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyRecord](tag, "MY_RECORDS") with Commons {
  def a = column[String]("A", O.PrimaryKey, O.Length(123))
  def b = column[String]("B", O.Length(123))

  def * = (a, b, common) <> (MyRecord.tupled, MyRecord.unapply)
}
```

It's not perfect but it helps avoid duplication without it being to difficult to understand.